# Positive and increasing function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f\geq 0$. 
There exists a constant $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ such that $f(y)\geq \varepsilon \left( \frac{y}{x}\right) f(x)$ for every $y\geq x\geq 0$. 
Is it possible to conclude that $f$ is increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that conclusion does not hold.

$\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is the slope of the line through $(0, 0)$ and $(x, f(x))$. If that slope is globally bounded above and below by constants $0 < c_1 < c_2$
$$ 
 c_1 \le \frac{f(x)}{x} \le c_2 \quad \text{for } x > 0
$$
then
$$
f(y) \ge \frac {c_1}{c_2} \frac yx f(x)
$$
for $y \ge x > 0$. So any function whose graph lies between two lines with slope $0 < c_1 < c_2$ through the origin satisfies the condition, but such functions are not necessarily increasing.

A concrete (continuous) counter-example:
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x & \text{ for } 0 \le x \le 2 \\
4-x & \text{ for } 2 \le x \le 3 \\
x - 2 & \text{ for }  x \ge 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
 \frac 13 \le \frac{f(x)}{x} \le 1
$$
for all $x > 0$, so that
$$
f(y) \ge \frac 13 \frac yx f(x)
$$
for $y \ge x > 0$, but $f$ is not increasing.

[image]

A differentiable (or arbitrarily smooth) counter-example can be constructed by modifying $f$ slightly around $x=2$ and $x=3$.

Comment: Another example is $f(x) = x + 2 \sin(x)$.